# Reading and setting tags using the PodioKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, podio

I try to set an item's **tags** using the PodioKit-API in Objective-C/Cocoa. The only thing that looks like tags was the definition of

```
PKTReferenceTypeTag
```

inside the PodioKit-Pod. I didn't find any information inside the API manual. The tag field is not shown when I walk through the available fields either:

```
[[PKTApp fetchAppWithID:appId] onComplete:^(PKTApp *app, NSError *error) {
    _appFields = [app fields];
    for (PKTAppField *pktAppField in _appFields) {
        NSString *pktAppFieldExtId = [pktAppField externalID];
        NSLog(@"Field_externalid %@", pktAppFieldExtId);
    }
}];
```

Maybe someone had the same problem or just has a tip into the right direction...

Thanks, Michael / Hamburg

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian from Podio here. Tags are not yet supported since the SDK is still in beta, but I will look into it and try to add it as soon as possible.

Comment: That explains why I didn't find it :) I'm looking forward to testing it! Thanx in advance - Michael